# Inconsistent number of samples

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

So I'm  trying to test my GRU model but everytime I run it I keep getting this error and I have no clue how to fix it?

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Your arrays `X` and `Y` have different sizes in the first dimension

Comment: yes, because my X uses a csv file and my Y uses another csv files

Comment: So if they are different sizes what do you expect to happen? In a supervised setting you probably want a 1-1 where every X has a corresponding Y

Comment: @IanQuah Ohhh okay I got something wrong, I though why is the test dataframe that is why I chose a different csv file for it because I want to use part of another csv for testing.